# Fluent NHibernate ClassMap<T> class

Tags: oracle, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a question-Does the class ClassMap take a lot of ram?
Can big Class of mapping cause slowness and abd performance?
thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> I have a question-Does the class ClassMap take a lot of ram?

No

> Can big Class of mapping cause slowness and abd performance?

not the class itself but the serializing deserializing when adding it to the Configuration object. However this cost is usually only paid once (app startup) and a huge mapping implies design flaws which will have much higher impact on other things than the mapping.